# Where to initialize TestNG TestContext

Tags: testng

I have a TestRunner class that starts my TestNG like this:

```
TestRunConfigs configs = TestRunConfigs.parseCommandLine(args);

TestNG testRunner=new TestNG();
testRunner.setXmlSuites(getXmlSuites(configs.TestSuites));
testRunner.run();
```

I need to provide some values to all tests in all my suites. I think ITestContext is the write way to do that. I just don't know where to do that. Any directions ?

Comment: Can you please add some more context to your question? What values are you looking to pass? How do your tests consume this values ? Please edit your question and add some sample code snippets also so that it helps us get a better perspective.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan I want to add string and object type attributes. These attributes will be used in the tests later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note: Please ensure you are using TestNG 7.0.0-beta1 which is the latest released version as of today**

The easiest way to get this done is to inject these parameters via a listener.

You basically implement `org.testng.ITestListener` interface using a class.
You instantiate this listener by passing in the required map of custom objects that your test requires.
Within your listeners `onStart(ITestContext ctx)` method, you pass on these attributes to the `ITestContext` object.

Below is a full fledged example that demonstrates this in action.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] {MyTestClass.class});
    Map<String, Data> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    attributes.put("data1", new Data("TestNG"));
    attributes.put("data2", new Data("Selenium"));
    attributes.put("data3", new Data("Maven"));
    LocalListener listener = new LocalListener(attributes);
    testng.addListener(listener);
    testng.setVerbose(2);
    testng.run();
  }

  public static class LocalListener implements ITestListener {
    private Map<String, Data> attributes;

    public LocalListener(Map<String, Data> attributes) {
      this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
      attributes.forEach(context::setAttribute);
    }
  }

  public static class MyTestClass {

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
      ITestContext ctx = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext();
      Set<String> attributeNames = ctx.getAttributeNames();
      attributeNames.forEach(
          attributeName -> {
            System.err.println("===>" + ctx.getAttribute(attributeName).toString());
          });
    }
  }

  public static class Data {
    private String name;

    public Data(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Data[" + name + "]";
    }
  }
}
```

The output is as below

```
===>Data[Maven]
===>Data[Selenium]
===>Data[TestNG]
PASSED: testMethod

===============================================
    Command line test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Command line suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```